# Check if column values are consecutive in SQL and assign them a row_number

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the next table :

| Device_id | Code | SESSION_ID | row_nb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MD50 | XSC547 | 7 | 450 |
| MD51 | LM678 | 7 | 451 |
| MD60 | SVF652 | 7 | 452 |
| VF35 | MMM547 | 7 | 550 |
| VF23 | NNN678 | 7 | 551 |
| MD60 | ABC652 | 7 | 800 |

I need to know if there is any solution how to create an extra-column called `test` as follow:

| Device_id | Code | SESSION_ID | row_nb | test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MD50 | XSC547 | 7 | 450 | 1 |
| MD51 | LM678 | 7 | 451 | 1 |
| MD60 | SVF652 | 7 | 452 | 1 |
| VF35 | MMM547 | 7 | 550 | 2 |
| VF23 | NNN678 | 7 | 551 | 2 |
| MD60 | ABC652 | 7 | 800 | 3 |

Each consecutive rows gets the same value in the `test` column is that possible with SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the difference between the row_nb (sorted ascending) and a sequence of consecutive numbers:

| row_nb | numbers | difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 6 | 4 | 2 |
| 7 | 5 | 2 |
| 11 | 6 | 5 |

**Note that each group of consecutive rows has same difference**.

Assuming your RDBMS supports window function you could do something like:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT row_nb, row_nb - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY row_nb) AS temp
  FROM t
)
SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY temp) AS test1, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY temp) AS test2
FROM cte
```

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hciuXq_2)

Comment: but the difference column is not sorted here I want sth like this 0, 1, 2 ... n in increasing manner

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Actually  `row_nb` column starts from 450 and not from 1 is that possible?

Comment: RANK/DENSE_RANK functions number rows starting from 1.

Comment: Can you check again my question please? I have changed the `row_nb` column

Comment: Check the db fiddle. The revised query does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Using [CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_true_event)

```
SELECT row_nb,
   CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(LAG(row_nb,1,row_nb-1) OVER(ORDER BY row_nb) != row_nb-1) 
   OVER (ORDER BY row_nb) + 1 AS test
FROM tbl 
ORDER BY row_nb;
```

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tbl(row_nb INT);
INSERT INTO tbl(row_nb) VALUES (450),(451),(452),(550),(551),(800);
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if you are using SQL server.

```
    with cte as
    (
    select 
        * , 
        lag(row_nb,1,0) over(order by row_nb) as lagged , 
        iif(row_nb - lag(row_nb,1,0) over(order by row_nb) > 1 , 0 , 1) as con
    from rowNum
    )
    select 
        row_nb ,
        row_number() over(order by row_nb) - sum(con) over(order by row_nb) as seq
    from cte
    order by row_nb;
```